# How to create an IAM role to list images in the Google Container Registry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I need to be able to assign a new role to a user who should only have access to list the images in the Google Container Registry. From my research I can't seem to find any actions in relation to container registry to assign to the role.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom role with `storage.objects.list` as permission. This role will let you to [list the images in your Container Registry repository](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/managing#listing_images):

```
gcloud container images list --repository=[HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]
```

However, users with this role might be able to list objects in other Cloud Storage buckets as well, if they know the name of buckets.

That being said, If you're looking for a more specific role/permission I'd recommend filing a feature request for this on [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/).